# Grid World Lab Difficulties

Tags: java

today I am basically trying to create some JAVA code that moves an actor to random spot on the grid if it is open. This is what I have so far but I'm having several problems. I am confused on how to check if the random spot is open. I used

```
if (null == E get(Location loc))
```

but it is not working and I get four errors. Can anyone explain? Thanks.

EDIT: After correcting my errors, the part I am currently having difficulty with is the while loop. I want this loop to run until the actor has moved to a random space. I am currently trying to use

```
while (place = getLocation());
```

Basically, I am attempting to make it run while the place it started with is the same place as it is in presently. I am still getting errors though.

EDIT: After editing my code, I am now only getting 2 error messages. Basically I don't get why I am getting these, can anyone help me?

```
 F:\Lab III Car and Teleporter\Teleporter Project\TeleporterActor.java:42: error: cannot find symbol
                if (null == get(loc))
                            ^
      symbol:   method get(Location)
      location: class TeleporterActor
    F:\Lab III Car and Teleporter\Teleporter Project\TeleporterActor.java:46: error: incompatible types
            while (place = getLocation());
                         ^
      required: boolean
      found:    Location
    2 errors



public void act()
    {
        Location place = getLocation();
        Grid<Actor> gr = getGrid();
        int cols = gr.getNumRows();
        int rows = gr.getNumCols();
        do
        {
            Location loc = new Location(Math.random() * rows - 1, Math.random() * cols - 1);
            if (null == get(loc))
                moveTo(loc);

        }
        while (place = getLocation());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is incorrect syntax.  You need to use 'new' to create new objects.

`Location loc = new Location(Math.random(rows) - 1, Math.random(cols) - 1);`

You also need a condition within the `while()` clause.  While what?

Finally your syntax is off in the if check:

`if (null == E get(Location loc))` - what are you trying to do?  You create a new location, so how it is possibly going to be null?

Comment: You are right about the new part. Thank you. The while code is another one of my problems. I'm trying to make this loop continue until there are no spaces left but I'm thinking this would result in a never ending loop unless I knew a specific way. For the last part, I'm trying to check if the location is open, otherwise my actor cannot move there.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use the definition of a method to call it. If a method is defined as

```
public int doit(double d) { ...
```

then you would use it like this

```
int result = doit(12.32);
```

So, applying to your if you would write

```
if (null == get(loc))
```

assuming that get(loc) returns a null value if it is empty.

To create your location (you probably have problem with that also unless you have a static method Location. You probably want

```
Location loc = new Location(Math.random(rows) - 1, Math.random(cols) - 1);
```

Comment: Ok, I'll implement what you said.